# correct form of struct for strings (or byte array) when importing Labview DLL into python (using ctypes)

Tags: python, dll, cluster-computing, ctypes, labview

I'm trying to import a DLL (created in Labview) into python. 
I've reduced it to a very simple Labview VI, a string goes into a cluster, the cluster is a function in the DLL i.e. the function is: void TestCluster(Cluster *outputCluster)
I can get everything but strings and arrays to read in from a cluster. I think I just don't have the correct Struct (?).

Has anyone done this? There's a partial guide: 
http://www.ni.com/white-paper/8911/en/

It might also be due to my little knowledge of ctypes in Python too.

Sample Python code for the import:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, string
from ctypes import *

class byteArrayStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("dimSize", c_int),("bytes", c_uint8 )]

class clusterStructure(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("stringField", c_char*4 ),
                ("byteArray", byteArrayStructure )]

dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("test.dll")
libc = cdll.msvcrt

def testMain():
    retValue = 0
    try:
        clusterIn = clusterStructure()
        dll.TestCluster( byref(clusterIn) )

        print clusterIn.byteArray.bytes 
        print cast(clusterIn.byteArray.bytes,c_char_p)

    except ValueError, Argument:
        retValue = "Error: " + str(ValueError) + "  " + str(Argument)
    return retValue

testMain()
```

edit:

structs from test.h,

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t dimSize;
    uint8_t elt[1];
} Uint8ArrayBase;
typedef Uint8ArrayBase **Uint8Array;
typedef struct {
    LStrHandle elt1;
    Uint8Array unsignedByteArray;
} Cluster;

void __cdecl TestCluster(Cluster *outputCluster);

MgErr __cdecl LVDLLStatus(char *errStr, int errStrLen, void *module);

/*
* Memory Allocation/Resize/Deallocation APIs for type 'Uint8Array'
*/
Uint8Array __cdecl AllocateUint8Array (int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl ResizeUint8Array (Uint8Array *hdlPtr, int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl DeAllocateUint8Array (Uint8Array *hdlPtr);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Please show the C struct definitions. As is, `c_uint8` is a single byte, so you're trying to cast some address in the low 256 bytes of your address space as a `char *` pointer.

Comment: ok, I've edited them in, thanks :)

Comment: You're missing the definition of `LStrHandle`, so I can't say if you've done that right. But the `bytes` field should be `c_uint8 * 1`, and the `byteArray` field should be `POINTER(POINTER(byteArrayStructure))`. It's interesting that it's a pointer to a pointer. That suggests it points at an array of `byteArrayStructure` pointers.

Comment: Also, I suggest you keep the names consistent with the C API. It's needlessly confusing to have multiple names for the same structures. For anyone familiar with the API your private names will be meaningless. If you have to search through the headers or source code (if available), or debug with symbols in a native debugger, then you have to remember the source names.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate and deallocate strings, arrays, and clusters because LabVIEW expects a [full and complete object owned by *its* memory manager](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/5719/en/#toc2) instead of Python's in case it needs to modify them (add/remove array elements or string characters). For example, [VIKit](https://github.com/wireddown/VIKit) has a LabVIEW-built library that uses strings and clusters in its entry points.

- [Allocating a string in C](https://github.com/wireddown/VIKit/blob/master/source/c/VISharedFunctions.c#L36)
- [Allocating an array of clusters](https://github.com/wireddown/VIKit/blob/master/source/c/VIQueryBuildSpecs.c#L64)

For more information, while this link is the reverse (a C DLL called from LabVIEW), the examples here include clusters, strings, and arrays: [Calling C/C++ DLLs Containing Simple and Complex Datatypes from LabVIEW](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-9079).

Comment: That's good to know for when Jeff gets that far. But we're still getting the data types and structures defined properly. You seem to have the LabVIEW experience to provide a complete answer with tested example code. I'll be happy to help with any ctypes questions you may have.